# Background noise while playing song

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to make a music box out of my PI, like a replacement to wifi-music players.

So here's what I've done

I've installed ArchLinux flavour on the pi.
I've installed mpd and I'm using the default alsa output for audio.

When I give `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav` I hear a women saying "Front Left" but there is background noise when the song starts playing and it remains even after the song ends. (this background noise is similar to the noise we hear when we increase the volume in old tape recorders without playing anything)

I've tried with pulseaudio as well. Same problem. If I kill the pulseaudio instance the noise vanishes.

How do I eliminate this noise?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvRhvOr0TYo.  The noise you are hearing is static, and it is probably either a bad recording, which the youtube link shows how to fix, or it is a bad cord.  If that's the case, you just need to buy a new cable.

Comment: I would downvote this answer if I could: Asking people to watch a Youtube video for getting some information is not helpful on a Q&A platform like this.